# Trying to use importxml in google sheets to extract a value from a website, but it returns a completely different value than I am selecting

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

[image of my google sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKXgo.png)

I am trying to create a sheet where I want to scrape values from [www.tapology.com](http://www.tapology.com) of individual fighters and fill columns created like fighter's name, his record, where he is from, etc.

I would like to scrape some values of this fighter so I started with name:

https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/119825-dominik-mazur

I put together something like this:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/119825-dominik-mazur", "//div[@id='stats']/ul[1]/li[1]/span[1]")
```

The XPath should lead to the name of the fighter which is Dominik Mazur, but for some reason it returns a different fighters name at random.

I guess it gets all the names that have the same structure, but I have no idea how to single out the value that I'm looking for.

Generally my goal is to create a google sheet where I paste a link to any fighter's tapology and it fills my sheet with the information I want instead of me manually typing everything.

Unfortunately I am not a programmer or very technical person so I would really appreciate your help. If anything is unclear please let me know.

Comment: weird! is this a joke? I had never seen this behavior beforewards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Try this

```
=arrayformula(split(transpose(split(scraping("yourURLhere"),"♥")),"♦"))
```

with custom function

```
function scraping(url){
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm,"")
  var data = source.match(/<div class='details details_two_columns' id='stats'>[\s\S\w]+?<\/div>/g)
  return (data[0].replace(/<li>/g,'♥').replace(/<span>/g,'♦').replace(/<\/li>|<strong>|<\/strong>|<\/span>/g,'').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g,''))
}
```

### Scrapping multiple urls

```
function infoTapology(url){
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm,"")
  var data = source.match(/<div class='details details_two_columns' id='stats'>[\s\S\w]+?<\/div>/g)
  var infos = data[0].replace(/<li>/g,'♥').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/g,'').replace(/&#39;/g,'’').replace(/&quot;/g,'”').split('♥')
  var result = []
  infos.forEach(function(info){
    var x = info.split(':')[0]
    if (info) {x=info.replace(x+':','')}
    result.push(x)
  })
  return([result])
}
```

[image]

### A comparison between importxml and custom function:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1se1lWH4g4OSvAW2NldjGiTDS5XB19_5QwSBpMqVRy84/copy

Comment: This is definitely a step closer to the goal! What if I want the function returns to be automatically dumped into a separate sheet where that information would be sorted and automatically updated, since the fighter record is not fixed? Like to have a separate sheet where I add rows of links to the fighters, and another sheet where all this information I am looking for is added. Suppose I create columns for name, age, record, etc. I would like the rows to those columns to be filled in with the information from the links on that other sheet. I don't know if this makes sense.

Comment: Can you provide a short list of urls?

Comment: Sure, for example:

https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/162087-tobiasz-le
https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/121479-sebastian-przybysz
https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/247883-patryk-semeniuk
https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/fighters/241447-daniel-alot

Comment: I have modified my answer, take a new copy of my spreadsheet

Comment: Awesome! Now I can work with it. There are still small details that can be improved, such as the fact that the height shows as 5&#39;10&quot, or that the height and reach are not shown separately, but I do not want to bother you anymore because you really helped me a lot and I'm terribly grateful because I would not have figured it out myself. But if you want, I would even be willing to pay you as long as it does not break the rules of this site.

Comment: No payment, it was a challenge and a pleasure. I will try to find a solution for `5&#39;7&quot;` ... and I still not understand why importxml doesn't work !

Comment: I have added `.replace(/&#39;/,'’').replace(/&quot;/,'”')` to remove `&#39;` and `&quot;`

Comment: Wow, appreciate it! Thank you so much once again.